# How to force Garbage Collection?

Tags: xcode, macos, build, garbage-collection, dylib

Is there any way that remains to build an Objective-C app with Garbage Collection?

I am writing a library to enhance a Mac app (I thus run the app with `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES='/path/to/dylib' /Applications/Original.app/Content/MacOS/Original`).
When I run this though, I first had issues because my lib used ARC, unlike the original app. Now I have disabled ARC, but I get this runtime error, before the original app crashes:

```
objc[610]: '/Users/me/mylib/myLib.dylib' was not compiled with -fobjc-gc or -fobjc-gc-only, but the application requires GC    
objc[610]: *** GC capability of application and some libraries did not match
```

However, it looks like Apple has now removed the support for plain old GC to favour ARC instead.
I have tried to use `GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC` from XCode, or the `-fobjc-gc` argument for gcc (or clang), but I get this compiler error: `garbage collection is no longer supported`.
Looks like I'm stuck... Is there any way to force build my lib with GC? I think I might use an old version of LLVM/gcc that would still support GC, but is there an easier way?
Note: I am using XCode 6.1 and Yosemite, the original app (and therefore my lib) is 32-bit.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_1.html): -

> *Xcode 5.1 no longer supports building OS X apps that use garbage collection; attempting to build such targets results in a build error.*

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood as well. The question is then, is there a way to circumvent this limitation? I won't be able to build my lib with XCode nor with the official LLVM compiler, but maybe some tricks (outside XCode obviously) would allow me to build it?

Comment: To my knowledge, the easiest way is to use an old version of XCode. As the newer compilers no longer support it, I doubt you will be able to use them.

Comment: Well, that's what I'll try then. I would have liked to avoid it, but it looks this is the only way though...
Luckily I have kept an old HDD with Snow Leopard on it (with old versions of XCode and compiler), I'll grab it back from its drawer where it is merely collecting dust :)

Comment: OK, just to give a feedback to this question, I finally found an ARC version of the software I wanted to add my lib to. So this kind of fixed my original problem.  
But for the record, and to conclude with, I think we can say I was stuck, as only using back an old version of the compiler would have helped... Thanks for your help anyway!